# Proper jsdoc on a class

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

Is the following a correct usage of JSDoc on a class? The code is trivial but I'm more interested in if this is an idiomatic usage of it or I'm missing somethings:

```
class Person {

    /**
     * Create a Person
     * @param {string} name
     * 
     */
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Print a salutation for that person
     * @returns {number} The number 1 if successfully invoked
     */
    say_hello() {
        console.log(`Hello ${this.name}`);
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Additionally, I'm using VSCode, are there extensions that help with creating this boilerplate?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/get-javascript-intellisense-in-visual-studio has information

Comment: type `/**TAB` and VSC will create a template/snippet for you